# Find the value of $a$ and the value of the limit

Tags: calculus

If there is a number $a$ such that

$$\lim_{x \to -2}\frac{3x^2 + ax + a + 3}{x^2 + x -2}$$
exists. Find the value of $a$ and the value of the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $x = -2$ the function is undefined so (x+2) must be a factor of both the numerator and denominator.

Numerator(-2) = 0
$$ 3(4) + (-2a) + a + 3 = 0 : a = 15$$

$$\lim_{x \to -2}\frac{3x^2 + 15x + 18}{x^2 + x -2} = \lim_{x \to -2}\frac{(x+2)(3x+9)}{(x+2)(x-1)} = \lim_{x \to -2}\frac{(3x+9)}{(x-1)} = -1$$